# Can I use a WildCard for a mstest cmd category filter?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, cmd, mstest

I am trying to run some tests from CMD using mstest, Some of my tests have mutiple categories. I want all of them to run except in one case.

Is there a way where I can wildcard the category filter ie: `/category:"*&!CI"`

**EDIT**

Can I perhaps use regular expressions? what should my pattern be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Below are your options. If these options do not tick your boxes I would recommend splitting your test into different assemblies and use the /testcontainer option to create different "playlists". That also makes sense if they are of different nature (hence you do not want to run them together). What is your use case?

You can only use the /category option one time per command line, but you can specify multiple test categories with the test category filter. The test category filter consists of one or more test category names separated by the logical operators '&', '|', '!', '&!'. The logical operators '&' and '|' cannot be used together to create a test category filter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category